# Manifold and the topology of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

A manifold $M$ is defined in particular as being locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Homeomorphisms can be defined in terms of how they map open sets, namely an homemorphism $f$ and its inverse $f^{-1}$ have to map open sets to open sets. Then, it looks like the definition of manifold depends on which topology you use in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. What I mean is that a local map from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ may or may not be an homeomorphism depending on which topology one uses in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. This indeed looks very weird. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: The point is that when you define manifolds you use $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ endowed with the *standard topology*.

Comment: But in principle one could use a different topology to define a manifold, is that right? Is there an example of such construction?

Comment: In principle one can use different topologies, but the point of defining manifolds is to have spaces that locally resembles a space with whom you are familiar, and topologically you are familiar with $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology. The fact is that euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a lot of properties that are well known and understood, while this is in general not true for other topologies. Moreover one would like to do  *calculus* on manifolds and you basically know how to do calculus in the standard $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.